# Group BY with multiple selects (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Im having a problem using group by with multiple selects. I want to select the minimum bid offer price for each Auction. But I also have to get the name of the user who made that Bid. As you can see in the results, I get multiple results for each auction, and if I remove elements from the Groupby statement I get an error message. How can I groupy by ID_Auction and still show the name of the User? Thanks for the help

```
SELECT A.ID_AUCTION,MIN(B.PRICE) AS PRICE,U.NAME
    FROM AUCTION A,BIDS B,USERS U,PRODUCT P
    WHERE  P.TYPE='CocaCola'
    --Joins
    and A.ID_AUCTION=B.ID_AUCTION
    and BID.ID_USER=U.ID_USER
    and A.ID_PRODUCT=P.ID_PRODUCT
    GROUP BY A.ID_AUCTION,U.NAME;

ID_AUCTION   PRICE         NAME                                     
---------- ----------  -------------- ------------------------------------------
    27         25         Andrew                                    
    28         40          John                                    
    27         30         Michael                                     
    28         35          Peter
```

The Output I Desire :

```
ID_AUCTION   PRICE         NAME                                     
---------- ----------  -------------- ------------------------------------------
    27         25         Andrew                                                                                                         
    28         35          Peter
```

Comment: This looks more like a problem with join rather than with group by. Could you provide the input data?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.ID_AUCTION,MIN(B.PRICE) AS PRICE,U.NAME
    FROM AUCTION A,BIDS B,USERS U,PRODUCT P
    WHERE  P.TYPE='CocaCola'
    --Joins
    and A.ID_AUCTION=B.ID_AUCTION
    and BID.ID_USER=U.ID_USER
    and A.ID_PRODUCT=P.ID_PRODUCT
    GROUP BY A.ID_AUCTION,U.NAME;
```

Should probably be like:

```
SELECT A.ID_AUCTION, U.NAME, B.PRICE as PRICE
from AUCTION A
inner join (SELECT ID_AUCTION, NAME, MIN(Price) from Bids order by 1,2,3) B
ON a.ID_AUCTION = b.ID_AUCTION
inner join Users U
ON B.ID_USER = U.ID_USER
inner join Product P
ON A.ID_PRODUCT = P.ID_PRODUCT
WHERE P.TYPE = 'CocaCola'
GROUP BY A.ID_AUCTION, U.NAME
```

I've never seen joins work the way you did it, but that might be an Oracle thing...actually I think that's considered bad practice in most SQL arenas...

Comment: It _used_ to be the only way to do joins.  Currently is officially deprecated, because it puts conditions away from the things being joined (and `OUTER JOIN`s can behave strangely).  Oh, that `ORDER BY` probably isn't necessary.  And you likely don't need the outer `GROUP BY` either.... Although actually, you have a syntax error - there's no `ID_USER` column in the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try, this will do the trick. It is ok with the coding style. Some old systems still work well with the ANSI-89 SQL style:

```
SELECT A.ID_AUCTION,
       B.PRICE,
       U.NAME
FROM AUCTION A,
     BIDS B,
     USERS U,
     PRODUCT P
WHERE P.TYPE='CocaCola' --Joins

  AND A.ID_AUCTION=B.ID_AUCTION
  AND B.ID_USER=U.ID_USER
  AND A.ID_PRODUCT=P.ID_PRODUCT
  AND B.PRICE = (SELECT MIN(bids.PRICE) FROM BIDS     --get only the bid with MIN price
                 WHERE bids.ID_AUCTION = A.ID_AUCTION);
```

Comment: Actually, it's vastly preferred to **not** use this style, which is officially deprecated.  It's preferred to explicitly list joins, as this style tends to mask missing join conditions.  Although pretty much all RDBMSs still support this syntax... This appears like it should get the desired answer, though.

Comment: I work for Regulatory Dept of the biggest Option Exchange located in Chicago, US. And all its batch jobs (~90) is using ANSI-89 coding style. When you work for an old system with old peoples, you can not just use a new style :) But I prefer to try some thing new.

Comment: @clockwork-muse it is old style and  should not be used, I agree.. But is **not** deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from 
(
SELECT A.ID_AUCTION,B.PRICE,U.NAME,
 Dense_Rank() over (partition by ID_AUCTION order by Price Asc)AS Rank
    FROM 
    AUCTION A
    JOIN
    BIDS B
    ON A.ID_AUCTION=B.ID_AUCTION
    JOIN
    USERS U
   ON BID.ID_USER=U.ID_USER
   JOIN
    PRODUCT P
   ON A.ID_PRODUCT=P.ID_PRODUCT
    WHERE  P.TYPE='CocaCola')
   where rank='1'
```

Answer (score -1):

First should just group by A.ID_AUCTION and second on your select you could try a min(U.NAME)

```
SELECT A.ID_AUCTION,MIN(B.PRICE) AS PRICE,min(U.NAME)
FROM AUCTION A,BIDS B,USERS U,PRODUCT P
WHERE  P.TYPE='CocaCola'
--Joins
and A.ID_AUCTION=B.ID_AUCTION
and BID.ID_USER=U.ID_USER
and A.ID_PRODUCT=P.ID_PRODUCT
GROUP BY A.ID_AUCTION;
```

Comment: how does the minimum name help this at all?

Comment: Another way to solve it is to have an external query doing another min like 
    select distinct(A.ID_AUCTION), min(price) from (
    SELECT A.ID_AUCTION,MIN(B.PRICE) AS PRICE,U.NAME
    FROM AUCTION A,BIDS B,USERS U,PRODUCT P
    WHERE  P.TYPE='CocaCola'
    --Joins
    and A.ID_AUCTION=B.ID_AUCTION
    and BID.ID_USER=U.ID_USER
    and A.ID_PRODUCT=P.ID_PRODUCT
    GROUP BY A.ID_AUCTION,U.NAME) as xxx

You need to check the syntax but should be something like that.

Comment: The min on name would be just a trick to force a single result to return

Comment: Thanks for the answers. The min really forced a single result output. But I get the data wrongly displayed

Comment: Yeah, thats kind of expected. Give it a try to the SQL on my first comment, that would be another way to solve it.

Comment: Min seems gimicky when there is things like LIMIT 1 that accomplish the same thing and have the benefit of being intended for that use

Comment: You'r right in this scenario doing min on the name is a hack but also doing limit  1 wont accomplish what he was trying to do.